# optimal kinect/xtion placement with regard to object recognition

Tags: ros, kinect, tabletop, 3d-object-recognition, xtion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I am wondering, if there is some kind of best practice out there or someone could share her/his experience about how to best place the Kinect, Xtion or a similar device on a robot.

To be more specific, I am thinking about which viewing angle is necessary to get good results for object recognition, e.g. with objects on a table.
Is there an optimal viewing angle - maybe 45 degrees?

I would be happy, if somebody doing table-top manipulation, e.g. with the PR2 + Kinect, could tell me about the viewing angles for which object recognition works well.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30978/optimal-kinect/xtion-placement-with-regard-to-object-recognition/) by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2062 on 2012-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

well, it all depends on the technique you use, it is that simple: template techniques like LINEMOD will need the same view points that you acquired during training, feature based ones can be a bit more robust to warping and so on.

Train your detector in angle/scale/illumination in the same way you will detect your object and accuracy will increase.

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2012-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1